# Provide a range selection tool/utility to the user in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to develop a user form in Excel 2007 VBA and want to provide a user with a range selection icon, something like this:  [image: Range Selection Icon]

However, I have not been able to find any built-in form design tool or any online tool which provides this or at least gives me an idea. If anyone has any idea about this, I will greatly appreciate their help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This control is called *RefEdit* control.

To use it, you have to first add it to the toolbox window by right-clicking in the toolbox window and selecting *Additional Controls...*. Then you select *RefEdit.Ctrl* and close the dialog.

Now you can select it in the toolbox and place it on your form.

Comment: Don't put it inside a Frame control or you'll get some crashes.  It's a pretty flaky control.  I've been experimenting with Peltier's alternative - more work, less crashing.  http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/refedit-control-alternative/

Comment: I was wondering how to use the same control Excel uses (as highlighted by babbupandey) instead of the buggy RefEdit :/

Comment: The RefEdit is the closest thing to the built-in control. I wish they'd fix the RefEdit, because it's a nicer user experience than the InputBox kludge I use to avoid the buggyness of the RefEdit.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative to using the *RefEdit.Ctrl* is to hook into some undocumented features of the *TextBox* control and use the *Application.InputBox* function.

There are two properties of the TextBox control that do not appear in the Properties dialog, that allow you to add a button on the right. They are *DropButtonStyle* and *ShowDropButtonWhen*.  When the button is clicked it will fire the *DropButtonClick* event for the control where you can show the input box.

Start by placing a *TextBox* control on the form.  Then add the following to the *UserForm_Initialize* procedure:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    txtRefersTo.DropButtonStyle = frmDropButtonStyleReduce
    txtRefersTo.ShowDropButtonWhen = frmShowDropButtonWhenAlways
End Sub
```

Then add an event handler to the *DropButtonClick* event as follows to capture the range using the *Application.InputBox* dialog:

```
Private Sub txtRefersTo_DropButtonClick()
    Me.Hide
    txtRefersTo.Text = Application.InputBox("Select the range", "Range Picker", txtRefersTo.Text, Type:=8)
    Me.Show vbModal
End Sub
```

The main advantage to this approach is that it allows you to place a control within a frame or on a separate tab without experiencing the issues associated with the *RefEdit.Ctrl*.  The disadvantage is that it requires a separate dialog to interact with Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is already almost a decade old, it still came up as my first Google search result so I'm going to post an answer as another approach to consider. The InputBox *with type set to cell reference* might be sufficient for many people's needs. The InputBox type does the drudge work of validating the user's response. See this article for how to use the InputBox types: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/vba-to-select-range-with-inputbox

Answer (score 0):

[I liked @krey answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38085788/5079799) which was basically a very simplified version of the link shared in @stifin answer --> https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/vba-to-select-range-with-inputbox

But both used "odd" names for the buttons and I think guides should use default names/values for easy understand and manipulation by end user. Additionally, I added a `CommandButton` to "run" the userform and a "select" statement for initial testing. I also wanted to provide an initial value as I try to pre-populate my userforms, but allow end user to override if needed.

Here is the final code snipppets utilizing a UserForm w/ one `TextBox` named `TextBox1` (default) and one `CommandButton` named `CommandButton1` (also default).

```
Option Explicit

Public rng As Range

Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  Me.TextBox1.DropButtonStyle = fmDropButtonStyleReduce
  Me.TextBox1.ShowDropButtonWhen = fmShowDropButtonWhenAlways
  Set rng = Range("A1:B4")
  TextBox1.Value = rng.Address(False, False)
End Sub

Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 rng.Select
 Unload Me
End Sub

Public Sub TextBox1_DropButtonClick()
    Me.Hide
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select the range", "Range Picker", TextBox1.Text, Type:=8)
    TextBox1.Value = rng.Address(False, False)
    Me.Show
End Sub
```