# How do I enable a range selector on an Excel ribbon bar?

Tags: excel, ms-office

What is the standard practice for adding range selection controls to a ribbon bar in Excel? I'm creating an Add-In and need to enable the user to define a series of ranges.  Here's a link to a question with an illustration of what I want [Provide a range selection tool/utility to the user in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507350/provide-a-range-selection-tool-utility-to-the-user-in-excel-vba).  The answer to the question however only works in the context of a winform.  My research suggests you can't use RefEdit controls directly in a ribbon bar.  Is that true? If so, what solution do you recommend? I considered creating a button that triggers a popup containing a RefEdit control, but that strikes me as a poor user experience since it involves additional clicks by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you are correct: the RefEdit control cannot be used within a ribbon. However, you can use a button control to populate an editBox control with the currently selected range, using the editBox's `getText` dynamic attribute. This will not only place a control within the ribbon that displays the selected range and holds the value there with a single click, but -- if needed -- other automated processes can be executed as well.

Comment: Thanks.  I also just learned that it's not just the ribbon that lacks RefEdit but rather managed code in general.  That's really surprising to me.