# VBA Chart using a Range as a messagebox

Tags: vba, charts, range, messagebox

I am trying to create a chart but have a pop-up box ask you to select the range as this will change each month.

The code i have below asks for a range then it doesn't create the chart.
Any help would be help

```
Sub test()
'Set up the variables.
Dim rng As Range

'Use the InputBox dialog to set the range for MyFunction
Set rng = Application.InputBox("Range:", Type:=8)
  Exit Sub
 'Call MyFunction
ActiveCell.Value = MyFunction(rng)
End Sub

Function MyFunction(rng As Range) As Double
MyFunction = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=rng
End Sub
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `Exit Sub` and `End Sub` like so:

```
Sub test()
    'Set up the variables.
    Dim rng As Range

    'Use the InputBox dialog to set the range for MyFunction
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Range:", Type:=8)

     'Call MyFunction
    ActiveCell.Value = MyFunction(rng)
End Sub

Function MyFunction(rng As Range) As Double

    MyFunction = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=rng
End Function
```

The first exit sub was preventing `test` from calling `Myfunction`.  `End Sub` has no [earthly business](http://ll-media.tmz.com/2011/08/01/0801-shawshank-sub.jpg) within a function.

The [RefEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507350/provide-a-range-selection-tool-utility-to-the-user-in-excel-vba) control might provide a better user experiance, for selecting ranges.  It's less likely than an Inputbox to return an invalid range.