# Excel VBA Vlookup where user chooses what cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a macro to do a vlookup between 2 different sheets within the same workbook, but sometime the layout of the cells changes so I wish to be able to add a dialog box that will allow the user to select what they are looking for and what list they would like to compare against but am not sure how to do this.

This is my code thus far:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-59],ONCE!C[-49],1,0)" 
Range("BI2").Select 
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("BI2:BI208032") 
Range("BI2:BI208032").Select 
Selection.Copy 
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _ :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO! It may be useful to see your macro, Pferd676!

Comment: Be Pre warned I am an utter noob at this so my macro could be rubbish I have no idea.  
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-59],ONCE!C[-49],1,0)"
    Range("BI2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("BI2:BI208032")
    Range("BI2:BI208032").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

Answer (score 1):

You can use InputBox like this:

```
myValue = InputBox("Give me some input")
```

[image]

Comment: Try copy and paste :) In "myValue" you will get the answer of the user.

Comment: much appreciated.do you know if it is possible to get the box tat the wizard uses instead?

Comment: No, I don't know it.

Comment: No problem. Not quite what I was looking for but a step in the right direction

Comment: The control you are looking for is called the *RefEdit*.  See this previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507350/provide-a-range-selection-tool-utility-to-the-user-in-excel-vba) for more.  Using the *RefEdit* is more complex than @duDe's approach.