# How to have user input a cell with a userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am building a userform with VBA. I want to be able to generate a list of random numbers, and have the user input what cell they start in. I have a textbox called `txtStarting`and a range called `userstarting`.

```
Private Sub txtStarting_Change()
Dim userstarting As Range
userstarting = txtStarting.Value
End Sub
```

The form doesn't let me type in the full value of the range. Like if I want to start with cell B1, as soon as I type in B, it gives me an error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507350/provide-a-range-selection-tool-utility-to-the-user-in-excel-vba

Comment: Which error did you get, and on which line?

Comment: `userstarting = txtStarting.Value` is not how you `set` a range.  It also needs to be a valid address.

Comment: Does `txtStarting` contain the sheet name or just a cell address? What sheet should the `Range` object be pulled from? The `ActiveSheet`? Or a specific one? In any case assigning an object reference will require the `Set` keyword, but before you take user input and use it to dereference a `Range` object, you need to take steps to handle an invalid input. This will require error handling.